# Read a wave file from IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, media

I would like to read a WAV file that I downloaded in isolatedStorage; actually I use a media Element on my Window which I set the source from the IsolatedStorageFileStream

```
Dim IsoRead As New IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream(MsgFN, FileMode.Open, Store)
Mainwindow.Playingsound.SetSource(IsoRead)
Mainwindow.Playingsound.Play()
```

But it seems not Working, I don't hear anything in the emulator.
Any idea why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link and tutorial will help you to solve your problem quick and easy.

I guess you only need to create a MediaStreamSource from your file which you opened and then you set this MediaStreamSource element as your MediaElements source.

```
var source = new Media.Mp3MediaStreamSource(audio);
```

You need to get the ManagedMediaHelpers project you will find a sample and the code in the Blog below.

[Tim Heuers Blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/download-and-store-media-for-playback-in-windows-phone-7-using-mediastreamsource.aspx)

Comment: The problem is I did'nt find a method which returns a MediaStreamSource in the System.Windows.Media namespace.

Comment: @Bahaïka Look at the blog he is using a helper project to create a MediaStreamSource